# Cannot install "Processing" plugin on MacOS + QGIS 2.9.3, fresh install

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have just installed a new MacBook Pro and QGIS, everything is fine but this strange error if I try updating or reinstalling the "Processing" plugin.

> The plugin is broken. Python said: cannot import name
>   AlgorithmDecorator

The full error log is at https://gist.github.com/giacecco/43c6b206239bfaa16f97 .

This appears not to be a duplicate, although many other issues are on Stackexchange regarding this plugin.

Uninstalling also fails. No error messages are shown, but the plugin still shows in the "Installed" pane.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that you'll get a better answer here than on the mailing list: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Processing-Plugin-Error-td5210055.html

It seems to be a more or less cosmetic issue since the installation eventually seems to work.